# interpolation syntax ipaddress_eth0 hiera data yaml

Tags: yaml, puppet, hiera

New to puppet and hiera data. Trying to interpolate text and a variable/value. How to make it print ip and properly adds a newline?

> common.yaml:

```
---
  myip: 'Here is my Public IP Adress: ${ipaddress_eth0}.\n'
```

> **Result:** Here is my Public IP Adress: ${ipaddress_eth0}.\n[root@localhost~]
>   #

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [Interpolation tokens](https://puppet.com/docs/hiera/3.3/variables.html#interpolation-tokens).  you should also look to use the [facts](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html#accessing-facts-from-puppet-code) hash e.g.

common.yaml

```
myip: 'Here is my Public IP Adress: %{facts['networking']['interfaces']['eth0']['ip']}.\n'
```

also the following will probably work

```
myip: 'Here is my Public IP Adress: %{facts['networking']['ip']}.\n'
```

to print this in puppet you need

test.pp

```
node /default/ {
  $myip = lookup(myip)
  notice($myip)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [hiera interpolation documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/hiera_interpolation.html) you should use this syntax:
`"%{facts.networking.interfaces.eth0.ip}"`

works on puppet 4, 5, 6